# In-app purchase development testing for different iTunes stores for Apple iOS

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Able to configure test users on iTunes Connect and able to successfully complete in-app purchase and restore operations - when I am connected to iTunes store in the US.

When I change my iTunes account to a different country store (India in this case), the in-app purchase for the test user (configured for India) doesn't work - goes to the loop on account verification dialog.

I followed the same exact steps as that of US iTunes store account purchase/restore operations, which was successful.

Does anyone tested in-app purchase on more than one app stores? Is there anything obvious that I am missing here?

thanks.

Comment: Create a test user for that app store so you should have different test user for different country store.

Comment: I do have a test user for each of the country. US Store test user able to complete purchase. India store user goes to Verification loop.